# How to fetch all elements of a particular column from an array of custom type in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have created a custom type in Postgres using

```
CREATE TYPE public.slot AS (start_time time, end_time time);
```

In a table `campaigns` I have created `slots_of_day` as an `array` of the above-mentioned custom type.

What I would like is a query that returns all the `start_time` from `slots_of_day` so that I can do a comparison operator with `ANY`. Something like `current_time < ANY(query to fetch all start time)`

Is there a way to do this in Postgres?

Comment: Unrelated, but: why don't you use a [range type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html)?

Comment: Also, if you used a regular normalized data model, your query would become simpler and faster.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe In this particular scenario, I don't want to use a normalized database as the join queries would be much slower than a denormalized one.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name In this particular scenario, I don't need a very specific timestamp-based range. If it was available I would have gone for it.

Comment: Range types are not limited to timesatmps, you can use them with `time` just as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With:

```
select * from campaigns;
 id |                 slots_of_day                  
----+-----------------------------------------------
  1 | {"(00:00:01,00:01:00)"}
  2 | {"(00:01:01,00:02:00)","(00:02:01,00:03:00)"}
(2 rows)
```

You can get:

```
select (unnest(slots_of_day)::slot).start_time from campaigns;
 start_time 
------------
 00:00:01
 00:01:01
 00:02:01
(3 rows)
```